# Why Error:input is undefined AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I am trying make an ajax request to php from angular js. But I am not getting the data I have sent by php file.

I'm getting this error:

Error:input is undefined

My source:

File view.html:

```
<div class="content-panel" >
    <div class="content-panel-title">
        <h2> Date : {{jalse.contentDate}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>{{jalse.contentAbstract}}</h4>
        <div>
            {{jalse.contentText}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

File app.js:

```
 (function () {
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

            .when('/', {
                controller: 'contentsCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/contents.php'
            })

            .when('/jalse/:jalseId', {
                controller: 'recordsCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/jalse.php'
            })

            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});

}());
```

File jalseFactory.js:

```
    (function () {

'use strict';

var jasleFactory = function ($http, $q) {

var factory = {};

factory.getJalse = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'includes/records.php'}).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.reject(data);
            });
    return deferred.promise;
  };
return factory;
};

jasleFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
angular.module('myApp').factory('jasleFactory', jasleFactory);

}());
```

File recordsCtrl.js:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var recordsCtrl = function($scope, $routeParams , jasleFactory) {
    var jalseId = $routeParams.jalseId;

    $scope.records = jasleFactory.getJalse();

    $scope.jalse = null;

    function init() {
        for (var i = 0, len = $scope.records.length; i < len; i++) {
            if ($scope.records[i].contentID == parseInt(jalseId)) {
                $scope.jalse = $scope.records[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    init();

};

   recordsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$routeParams', 'jasleFactory'];

    angular.module('myApp').controller('recordsCtrl', recordsCtrl);

}());
```

Comment: doesn't seems like the error is related to angular..its from some other code where you are using `input` variable which is not defined

Comment: thankful. There is also an Error: $scope.records is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is making an ajax and then assuming that the response is set the `records` variable, As you are dealing with async call you should call the method which are going to call on `$scope.records` inside its success.

**Factory Method**

```
factory.getJalse = function () {
    return $http({method: 'GET', url: 'includes/records.php'});
};
```

**Controller**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var recordsCtrl = function($scope, $routeParams, jasleFactory) {
        var jalseId = $routeParams.jalseId;

        jasleFactory.getJalse().success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.records = data.records;
            init(); //this will fix your error.
        }).
        error(function(error, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("error occured " + error)
        });
        $scope.jalse = null;
        function init() {
            for (var i = 0, len = $scope.records.length; i < len; i++) {
                if ($scope.records[i].contentID == parseInt(jalseId)) {
                    $scope.jalse = $scope.records[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //we will call this as soon as $scope.records gets filled
        //init(); 
    };
  recordsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$routeParams', 'jasleFactory'];

  angular.module('myApp').controller('recordsCtrl', recordsCtrl);

}());
```

**Update**

Your json is also not valid because it contains a malicious field which

```
"contentText": "1\ u0645\ u0637\ u0644\ u0628 < \/p>",
"3":"1\ u0645\ u0637\ u0644\ u0628 < \/p>",
```

If you remove this two field, you code will work as is

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7X7MhvVYHr5znk5AF6K1?p=preview)

Comment: I add code above and add Controller down code:  recordsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$routeParams', 'jasleFactory'];
angular.module('myApp').controller('recordsCtrl', recordsCtrl);
solved last error But error : Error: $scope.records is undefined

Comment: I add  <div class="content-panel" ng-init="init()">   solvede : Error: $scope.records is undefined  but show Nothing

Comment: Remove `ng-init` what you tried..and look at my edit

Comment: I Remove ng-init and added code above But not solve  -  show Nothing data record in view - retrieving data from server but not Search in recordsCtrl function init()  -   Nothing error

Comment: I print records in view But not search

Comment: @Mehdi recodrs are showing that means issue is fixed. now you are going on adding things..what is your exact issue?

Comment: I getting data from server in Factory and  after search with "jalseId" in Controller I print jalse in the view page . But  show Nothing data jalse

Comment: @Mehdi did you replace your factory method as I suggested?

Comment: @Mehdi what do you mean by go ahead..?

Comment: @Mehdi could you give me your response json..so that will give you working plunkr/fiddle ?

Comment: I am waiting for your response

Comment: @Mehdi sorry for late reply,..but you could look at it now http://plnkr.co/edit/7X7MhvVYHr5znk5AF6K1?p=preview

Comment: @Mehdi Glad to help you..Thanks :)